# Having trouble with recursive functions

Tags: c++, function, recursion

Can someone please help me understand this recursive function? Ive been following an online tutorial but Im stuck at this part:

```
int factorialFinder(int x){
    if(x==1){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return x * factorialFinder(x-1);
    }

}
```

So I know this function is used to calculate the factorial of an integer x but I dont understand the `return x * factorialFinder(x-1);`

does this line multiple the values for x by x-1 or does it first look for the base case THEN multiply the values? The way it was explained to me was that the function looks for x==1 and then it multiplies the values of x but this makes no sense to me.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the `if`, and run your code in the debugger. Watch what's going on. If your debugger lets you see call stack, take a look at it for better understanding of the mechanics of it.

Answer (score 1):

Lets consider x=4
so function call stack would be

```
factorialFinder(4) returns 4*factorialFinder(3)

factorialFinder(3) returns 3*factorialFinder(2)

factorialFinder(2) returns 2*factorialFinder(1)

factorialFinder(1) returns 1 *base condition*
```

Now just substitute return values. Since its a stack, last function call will be evaluated first

So

```
factorialFinder(1) = 1
factorialFinder(2) = 2*1
factorialFinder(3) = 3*2*1
factorialFinder(4) = 4*3*2*1
```

Looks are you are playing around recursion for the first time. It looks little confusing initially but its a great problem solving approach that lets you solve problems with minimal code. Explore it further!! and Hope it helps.